# Create the following matrix by typing one command. Do not type all individual elements explicitly

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create the following matrix in MATLAB:

```
M= [ 0 0 1 10 20
     0 0 3 8  26
     0 0 5 6  32
     0 0 0 0  0]
```

but I don't want to input all elements manually.

I tried `M (1:3,3:5)=[x;y;z]`

where

- `x` is the linspace of 1 to 5
- `y` is the linspace of 10 to 6
- `z` is the linspace of 20 to 32

but it doesn't work (the last row of zeros is missing). How can I create `M` in a smart way?

Comment: What language is this? MATLAB?

Comment: matlab c programming

Comment: I've added the tag. I don't have Matlab to play with-- couldn't you do something with `[0 0 1 10 20]` and `[0 0 2 -2 6]`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is some programming assignment, because otherwise I don't see a reason why this needs to be done in a single line. I'm also assuming that concatenating a vector of zeros is unwanted. Having said that here are several suggestions:

Suppose that your vectors are defined like so:

```
x = 1:2:5;
y = 10:-2:6;
z = 20:6:32;
```

The "cleanest" way (under the assumption of no-zero-vector-concatenation) is probably:

```
M = subsasgn(zeros(4,5),substruct('()',{1:3,3:5}),[x',y',z']);
```

Alternatively, if using external functions, you can use the [`insertrows` submission on FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9984-insertrows--v2-0--may-2008-):

```
M = insertrows(insertrows([(x)',(y)',(z)'],0,4)',0,[0,0])';
```

With two commands, and assuming that `M` doesn't exist, you can do:

```
M(2:4,3:5)=([fliplr(x)',fliplr(y)',fliplr(z)']);
M = flipud(M);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange question, but here you go, in one command. This assumes `M` is previously non-existent, and that `x`, `y` and `z` are defined as `x = 1:2:5; y = 10:-2:6; z = 20:6:36;`:

```
M(1:4,3:5) = [[x;y;z].'; zeros(1,3)];
```

You can of course avoid `x`, `y` and `z` by defining their values on the fly:

```
M(1:4,3:5) = [[1:2:5; 10:-2:6; 20:6:36].'; zeros(1,3)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one-liner that requires no other input(s) and creates the `linspace` values internally, here's one -

```
M(1:4,3:5)=[bsxfun(@plus,[1 10 20],bsxfun(@times,[2 -2 6],[0:2]'));zeros(1,3)]
```

Output -

```
M =
     0     0     1    10    20
     0     0     3     8    26
     0     0     5     6    32
     0     0     0     0     0
```